# 50unattended-upgrades not recognized or not working

Tags: unattended-upgrades, blacklist

I'm trying to add a couple postgis items to my unattended-upgrades blacklist. However, I have not been successful as both items below keep appearing in the upgrade confirmation.

In my /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades I added these items:

```
// Python regular expressions, matching packages to exclude from upgrading
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {

//added by JH 2019-11-11 to stop postgis pg errors
  "postgresql-11-postgis-2.5$";
  "postgresql-11-postgis-2.5-scripts$";
};
```

When I do the following, I still see both items in the section 'The following items will be upgraded:'

`sudo apt upgrade`

I've also rebooted the server but, no go.

When I do a dry run with the below, I still see these two packages included.

`sudo unattended-upgrades --debug --dry-run`

Is there something I should be doing e.g. restarting any services to get this to work?

Lastly, is the 'unattended-upgrades' package installed by default? I found the 50unattended-upgrades file in my /etc/apt/apt.conf.d already in place but, following another discussion thread, wanted to confirm this package was installed. My assumption being by not getting a message to the effect of 'This package already installed', I assumed it hadn't been previously.

`sudo apt install unattended-upgrades`

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm. Why `"package$";` instead of `"package";` ?

Comment: I understood package$ limited to the exact package name.

Comment: Did you try it without the '$' ?

Comment: I did and had the same result. Sorry for not specifying that as well.

Comment: An `apt upgrade` will NOT use unattended-upgrade settings, so seeing those package in the list of proposed upgrades seems like expected behavior. Please edit your question to show the complete output from `sudo unattended-upgrades --debug --dry-run`